# Modifying a plugin, but changes aren't reflected. AngularJS in an Ionic (Angular2) app

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, plugins

I am trying to modify a plugin, it is a calendar. When you press on the dates that are not part of the month (at the beginning and the end of the month) it changes to the next or previous month. I am trying to disable this, and I found what part of the code to change, but when I make the changes (or add a `console.log` message), nothing gets reflected when I execute `ionic serve`. One thing is, the calendar is written in `AngularJS` - while I am using Ionic, which uses `Angular 2`. The part of the code I am trying to change looks like this:

```
$scope.select = function (viewDate) {
                    console.log("in in in select &&&&&&&");
                    var selectedDate = viewDate.date,
                        events = viewDate.events,
                        views = scope.views,
                        dates,
                        r;
                    if (views) {
                        dates = views[scope.currentViewIndex].dates;
                        var currentCalendarDate = ctrl.currentCalendarDate;
                        var currentMonth = currentCalendarDate.getMonth();
                        var currentYear = currentCalendarDate.getFullYear();
                        var selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth();
                        var selectedYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();
                        var direction = 0;
                        if (currentYear === selectedYear) {
                            if (currentMonth !== selectedMonth) {
                                direction = currentMonth < selectedMonth ? 1 : -1;
                            }
                        } else {
                            direction = currentYear < selectedYear ? 1 : -1;
                        }

                        ctrl.currentCalendarDate = selectedDate;
                        if (direction === 0) {
                            if (ngModelCtrl) {
                                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(selectedDate);
                            }
                            var currentViewStartDate = ctrl.range.startTime,
                                oneDay = 86400000,
                                selectedDayDifference = Math.floor((selectedDate.getTime() - currentViewStartDate.getTime()) / oneDay);
                            for (r = 0; r < 42; r += 1) {
                                dates[r].selected = false;
                            }

                            if (selectedDayDifference >= 0 && selectedDayDifference < 42) {
                                dates[selectedDayDifference].selected = true;
                                scope.selectedDate = dates[selectedDayDifference];
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("is getting here &&^^%%$$");
                            //ctrl.moveOnSelected = true;
                            //ctrl.slideView(direction); <----- I AM COMMENTING THIS OUT TO STOP THE SLIDE!!!
                        }

                    ...
```

At the bottom of the above code block, I made an arrow pointing to the two lines I am commenting out. I also added `console.log` statements, one at the beginning of the function, and one in the middle, and neither of them are output into the console (the above is the `select` function which happens when a date on the calendar is selected).

The code structure of the plugin is like this:

```
angular.module("ui.rCalendar.tpls", ["templates/rcalendar/calendar.html","templates/rcalendar/day.html","templates/rcalendar/displayEvent.html","templates/rcalendar/month.html","templates/rcalendar/monthviewDisplayEvent.html","templates/rcalendar/monthviewEventDetail.html","templates/rcalendar/week.html"]);
angular.module('ui.rCalendar', ['ui.rCalendar.tpls'])
    .constant('calendarConfig', {
        formatDay: 'dd',
        formatDayHeader: 'EEE',
        formatDayTitle: 'MMMM dd, yyyy',
        formatWeekTitle: 'MMMM yyyy, Week w',
        formatMonthTitle: 'MMMM yyyy',
        formatWeekViewDayHeader: 'EEE d',
        formatHourColumn: 'ha',
        calendarMode: 'month',
        showEventDetail: true,
        startingDayMonth: 0,
        startingDayWeek: 0,
        allDayLabel: 'all day',
        noEventsLabel: 'No Events',
        eventSource: null,
        queryMode: 'local',
        step: 60,
        autoSelect: true,
        monthviewDisplayEventTemplateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar/monthviewDisplayEvent.html',
        monthviewEventDetailTemplateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar/monthviewEventDetail.html',
        weekviewAllDayEventTemplateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar/displayEvent.html',
        weekviewNormalEventTemplateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar/displayEvent.html',
        dayviewAllDayEventTemplateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar/displayEvent.html',
        dayviewNormalEventTemplateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar/displayEvent.html'
    })
    .controller('ui.rCalendar.CalendarController'

    ...

    .directive('monthview', ['dateFilter', function (dateFilter) {

           THIS IS WHERE THE SELECT FUNCTION IS

    ...
```

This is an `angularjs` plugin in an `Ionic` app, remember it is built on `Angular 2` not `angularjs`. Im not sure where the plugin javascript file gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong package folder, I didn't realized I had installed a typescript version.